# Formatting traceback

Tags: discussion, questions, formatting

A fair amount of SO questions need traceback to be answered and I feel like the most part of these questions do not format the traceback well.

Most of tracebacks are formated as citation, I don't know why people choose citation over code block. Why code block is better than citation: New lines, indentation & mono-space fonts.

So, is there any relevant reason to use citation for traceback or can I start editing every badly-formatted tracebacks I pass by?

Comment: I have seen this in android trace logs. Generally because the log itself seems to start with after a big gap when in codeblock

Comment: (if people could just said at least "yes" or "no", because downvote don't give me any answer here)

Comment: Program output should be formatted as code.

Comment: A fair amount of questions require editing to fix formatting goofs.  You can leave it to somebody else, especially so in [python], many hands make light work.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have any example here, but I seen people editing question only to pass raw traceback to citation. But are we ok using citation for traceback is just wrong?